# php limit what happens in 'while' loop

Tags: php, while-loop

I have some code that creates a divs for each result of a query.  My problem is that, I only want the same amount of divs created for the result set I'm limiting.

For example, this query produces about 8-9 rows however, in this case, if $busroute==2, and there are only 2 results that match this, I only want to to create 2 divs and close them.  Right now, as I have it, it's creating a div - /div set for each iteration of the "while" loop.

```
    <?php 

    mysql_data_seek( $result,0);
    while ($i2=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $busnumber=$i2['NAME'];
    $busroute=$i2['route'];
    $busdirection=$i2['direction'];
    $timediff=$i2['TimeDiff'];
    $timestamp=$i2['TIMESTAMP'];        
    if ($busroute=='2'){
    echo "<div class='businfo'>";
    echo "<p>Bus #: ".$busnumber."<br>Direction: ".$busdirection."<br>Bus Route : ".$busroute."<br>"; 
    echo "Timestamp : $timestamp</p>";
    }
    echo "</div>";
    }
```

?>

So, if $busroute==2, and there are two results where $busroute==2, then the following should only output twice.

```
    echo "<div class='businfo'>";
    echo "<p>Bus #: ".$busnumber."<br>Direction: ".$busdirection."<br>Bus Route : ".$busroute."<br>"; 
    echo "Timestamp : $timestamp</p>";
    }
    echo "</div>";
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

- d -

Comment: I'm not completely sure I understand what you're asking, but wouldn't foreach(mysql_fetch_array($result) { if ($busroute == 2) { echo "things"; }} work?

Comment: off topic: Be aware that the `mysql_xxx()` functions are deprecated and no longer supported. It is recommended to switch to an alternative API -- either `mysqli` or `PDO` -- as soon as possible.

Comment: Yes..thanks, I'm aware it's being deprecated but, for the moment I'm having to use it.  Then I I'll change everything over to mysqli or PDO.  thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code already looks OK for what you want.
I think "</div>" should be inside your IF.

Replace

```
if ($busroute=='2'){
echo "<div class='businfo'>";
echo "<p>Bus #: ".$busnumber."<br>Direction: ".$busdirection."<br>Bus Route : ".$busroute."<br>"; 
echo "Timestamp : $timestamp</p>";
}
echo "</div>";
```

with

```
if ($busroute=='2'){
echo "<div class='businfo'>";
echo "<p>Bus #: ".$busnumber."<br>Direction: ".$busdirection."<br>Bus Route : ".$busroute."<br>"; 
echo "Timestamp : $timestamp</p>";
echo "</div>";  
}
```

Comment: That worked.  Thanks :)  I'm still confused how that allowed the rest of the "<divs>" to be excuted for each iteration of the loop :/ Oh well, it works :)  Thanks again.

Comment: I know what you mean!! :P A ghost maybe?? :P

Comment: Ghosts!  Yes...sounds, legit :)  Thanks again.